# How to define url parameter type in node js router

Tags: node.js, types, router

```
router.get("/:tid/user/:uid?", getUser);
const params = req.params;
const query = req.query;
```

`/2/user/7?status=1&age=42`

Both params and query methods return the parameters(tid=2,uid=7, and status=1,age=42) as a string. is it possible to define the type of the parameter at router level?

Comment: You could use [`express-validator`](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/) to check the value being passed in.